# Mathematic formula for the voltage drop on R3

Tags: voltage, kirchhoffs-laws

Please help me understand how does LTSpice or any other simulation manage to measure the potential drop on R3 resistor (how does it get to the 9.329V value from 10V).

I am trying to simulate a short with the V2 voltage. I understand how the currents go, for example:

- 577uA current through R1 is calculated from (VR3-V1pos) / R1 = (9.329-5) / 7500 =0.0005772A
- 93uA current through R2 is calculated from (VR3-V1neg) / R2 = (9.329-0) / 100000 =0.0005772A
- 671uA equals to the sum of I1 and I2 => 577uA + 93uA = 670uA

I want, manual,on a paper, knowing both of the Vin and the value of the resistors to calculate the potential drop on the R3. I am thinking that it has to do with KVL but I can't remember. Can you please help me?

[image]

Comment: if you can redraw the circuit better it will be easier to find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use nodal analysis to determine the voltage at the central node, labeled 9.329V in your schematic. In other words, observe that the current entering the node (e.g. from V2) equals the current leaving the node (into V1 and through R2 to ground). Note that you can pick a direction of current and if you pick 'incorrectly', the value will just come out negative.
2. With that voltage determined, and knowing the value of V2 to be 10V, you simply take the difference and that is your drop over R3

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Voltage across R3 = V2 - Vout

From Millman's Theorem

Vout = ((V1/R1) + (V2/R3))/((1/R1) + (1/R2) +(1/R3))

Therefore voltage across R3 = V2 - ((V1/R1) + (V2/R3))/((1/R1) + (1/R2) +(1/R3))